# How to limit the width of a SeparatorField to a fixed value?

Tags: blackberry, field

I have a VerticalFieldManager that contains two ordinary Fields separated by a SeparatorField.  The second Field is much larger than the first, so the VFM scrolls up/down and right/left.

When I don't add the SeparatorField, the scrolling on the VFM works as expected - I am never able to scroll (either vertically or horizontally) past the contents of the second Field.

However, when I add the SeparatorField (with the default constructor), it appears to make the separator infinitely wide - I can scroll infinitely far to the right, well past the contents of the second field, and I never appear to reach the end of the separator.

**How can I tell the SeparatorField to only be as wide as necessary according to the contents of the second Field?**  I have tried overriding `getPreferredWidth()` on the SeparatorField, but this appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself, but I suspect overriding layout(int, int) should do it.
something like:

```
public static int MAX_WIDTH=20;
protected void layout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    super.layout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    this.setExtent(Math.min(this.getWidth(), MAX_WIDTH), this.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: This seems to have no effect - the separator is still infinitely wide.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my solution to this problem was to throw out the `SeparatorField` entirely, and draw the line where it needs to go in the `paint()` method.